# How to get annotations from PdfTron signed document in nodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdftron

I have a pdfTron document in NodeJS, this has an annotation with a handle signature

```
const pdfDoc = docViewer.getPDFDoc();
```

My question is, is possible to extract this annotation (as an image for example) without full document? I understand that is possible to get the annotation coordinates, but I did not find documentation about image extraction.

Comment: It is not totally clear what you are trying to accomplish. You want to get all the annotations from the entire document? Or you want to extract any images that may be in the PDF? It would help a lot if you could also explain what you want to do with the output, so that I can match you with the best output/solution.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to get the annotations inside document after a signature cycle, for example, 2 users sign the same document, then I want to store the respective signature in database for each user in base 64 or another file.